# Create a new Column based on the latest column with a value on a dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
orderID         m1              m2              m3      
1       2020-03-04      2020-03-04             NaT
2       2020-03-08             NaT             NaT
```

And i want to create a new column that displays the latest milestone (mn) available for an Order.

The output would look like something like this

```
orderID         m1              m2              m3          last_m_available
1       2020-03-04      2020-03-04             NaT                        m2
2       2020-03-08             NaT             NaT                        m1
```

How would i do this with python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap order of columns, test not missing values and use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
#if orderID is not index
df = df.set_index('orderID')

df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['last_m_available'] = df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
                m1         m2  m3 last_m_available
orderID                                           
1       2020-03-04 2020-03-04 NaT               m2
2       2020-03-08        NaT NaT               m1
```

If possible some rows with only missing values:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
mask = df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna()
df['last_m_available'] = np.where(mask.any(axis=1), mask.idxmax(axis=1), np.nan)
print (df)
                m1         m2  m3 last_m_available
orderID                                           
1       2020-03-04 2020-03-04 NaT               m2
2              NaT        NaT NaT              NaN
```

Comment: Tried that out but  having this error: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype.
Most probably due to the Dtypes of m

Comment: @Haalanam - I think is necessary working only with datetimes, first use `df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)` for convert to datetimes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataframe.dropna()` to get rid of empty columns for your list.

```
cols = df.dropna().columns
df['last_m_available'] = cols
print(df)

                m1         m2  m3 last_m_available
orderID                                           
1       2020-03-04 2020-03-04 NaN               m2
2       2020-03-08        NaN NaN               m1
```